# As a site builder, how can I learn when modules I use are (going to be) deprecated?

Tags: 7

I have a site that uses a relatively large number of modules (100+).  I do my best to keep up-to-date but recently I have become a little alarmed because I found that Heartbeat and Custom Breadcrumbs, two modules I use on my site, are likely to be deprecated in the near future.

I learned about Heartbeat's deprecation by visiting the module's page by chance when I was checking the documentation.  I learned about Custom Breadcrumbs possibly being deprecated from a comment here on *Drupal Answers*.

At the time I installed these modules (early last year), they were the most popular in their respective categories.  Heartbeat's maintainer was active and making releases every few weeks.

Now, a year later, they are being deprecated in favor of other modules.  I understand the reason for this, and I'm happy to migrate my site over to the replacement modules (well, maybe not happy, but I'll do it)-- however, I can't do this if I'm not informed that modules are going to be deprecated.  I only found out about these two by chance!

Is there any central resource that keeps track of deprecated modules?  Since I use so many, checking issue queues or even module's pages is not really a feasible option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could subscribe with RSS to tag data on projects such as:

- Maintenance status: [Unsupported](http://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/13032/0/feed)
- Development status: [No further development](http://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/16538/0/feed)

That can give you notice of deprecation assuming the relevant tag has been assigned to the project.

Answer (score 1):

## There is a module for it

I'm assuming that this question is about D6 (possibly even still D5?). In that case, apart from the prior answer, you may want to look at the "[Upgrade Status](https://www.drupal.org/project/upgrade_status)" module also. Here is an excerpt from its project page:

> ... checks the list of projects you have installed and shows their availability for the new version of Drupal core, which can be one of the following:
>
> - **Available**: A stable release of this project is available.
> - **In development**: A development release of this project is available, which can be installed for testing purposes.
> - **Not ported yet**: There are no releases available for this project.
>
> Clicking on any of the modules' boxes will show you notes about upgrading the project, as well as a link to download the new version.

I've used it on quite some D6 sites in the past (to get an idea of the feasibility to upgrade all contributed modules to D7). It worked great.

By the way, there is a [D7-dev version](https://www.drupal.org/node/2172249) of this module also, so I'm assuming that's a good sign for whenever D7 tp D8 is on the horizon ...

## Use the data on Drupal.org

Some more pointers to some other questions that I beieve might help aso to answer this question here:

- [Get more drupal.org project usage information](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87971/get-more-drupal-org-project-usage-information/153840?s=5%7C4.4997#153840).
- [Contrib statistics: Reported installs and downloads](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/157088/contrib-statistics-reported-installs-and-downloads/157089?s=2%7C7.3368#157089).

## Bonus tip

Even though not part of this question here, often times when you're considering upgrading you also want to have an idea of "Are there any tweaks (hacks) in any of our contributed modules that we need to be aware of?". Especially if somebody else first created the D6 site, and you're in charge of the D7 upgrade. Guess what, there's a module for it, it's called [Hacked!](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) ... Great module also I think ...

Comment: Thanks, actually this was originally a D7 question.  For example, Heartbeat was a D7 module that saw early development during the D7 beta but eventually was deprecated in favor of the Messages module, that didn't even exist during the time of the beta.