# Get more drupal.org project usage information

Tags: uri, community-official-site

Choosing a Drupal module has become an art-form.  Deciding if the module is active, used frequently, growing in usage, etc. is important.

I'm a site builder.  https://drupal.org/project/usage has lot's of good information but interested in levaring the view.  What kind of URL arguments are supported?  I know that:
`?sort=asc` will work, but can I filter by category, change time range or make a more sophisticated query?  I can add https://drupal.org/project/usage/webform and get more granular on a project basis but would like more control and to understand the URL arguments supported.

I didn't find any [Project](https://drupal.org/project/project) documents that were relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usage page comes from [project_usage_overview()](http://drupalcode.org/project/project.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/usage/includes/pages.inc#l77); it's not a View.  The only parameters are those provided by Drupal's *tablesort API*, "sort" and "order".

`?sort=asc` you've already discovered, and the other parameter changes the sort column (`?order=Project` would sort by project name).

Comment: Fantastic - thanks!  I wanted to see trending and some other info - I guess I would have to pull into a spreadsheet to analyze.  I also imagine I have to crawl to each project to get historical data beyond the last few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Great question! I'm struggling with the same kind of question, but then limited to any of the [charting modules available](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) in Drupal (or at least that I'm aware of ...).

The various "features" available/supported in any such module is, IMHO, only 1 of the criteria to decide for a specific module. But also (maybe even more?) important I think is what is in the very first paragraph of the question in the OP. Therefor I started to use the "[maintenance scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards)". Even though I started using it for "charting" modules, I also use it now for any other types of modules I need to decide about.

Without trying to highjack the original question here: I'm now trying to find a way to use something like JSON to periodically (like weekly) go get (retrieve) all sorts of data included somewhere on drupal.org ...

Something that might help for such JSON data is located at https://www.drupal.org/node/669910#comment-7432476 , which is includes a ZIP file with content like so:

> a feature that provides some data for Drupal.org. This will meet the requirements for security.drupal.org, it does not meet all the requirements listed above. The data is in JSON format. It will require that views_datasource be installed.

Comment: have you had some success in this?  I'm still trying to get good drupal module stats.

Comment: Refer to my updated answer from a few mins ago.