# Best way to get module and commit meta data from drupal.org

Tags: community-official-site

This is a broader question, but related to: [get-more-drupal-org-project-usage-information](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87971/get-more-drupal-org-project-usage-information)

**Goal: I'd like to get richer stats about modules.**

Choosing a module has become a very complicated process.  Things like recent commits, usage growth/decline, number of maintainers, etc. all factor in but drupal.org has (frankly) lousy tools for finding modules and http://drupalmodules.com/ is basically abandoned.

**Current Approach: Screen-scrape limited available stats like https://www.drupal.org/project/usage**

I've been grabbing some stats to help me make an informed decision but scraping seems archaic given the openness of drupal.

**Ideal Approach: Use published drupal.org API to query in JSON**

Does such a thing exist to harvest module info or is it necessary to scrape?  Even better would be to create a database or spreadsheet.

I have seen a [thread discussing](https://www.drupal.org/node/2186377) this, but looking for an implementation or concrete plan to implement.

IMO there is a desperate need to improve module transparency and data to help system builders better select appropriate modules.

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to find but this is what I was looking for:

**https://www.drupal.org/api**

> The following node types currently exist on drupal.org:
>
> book book_listing casestudy changenotice forum image organization
>   packaging_whitelist page project_issue project_core
>   project_distribution project_drupalorg project_module project_release
>   project_theme project_theme_engine project_translation story Of
>   particular interest is interacting with the issue queues. Some of the
>   field values returned by the api are the numeric representations in
>   the database. The following mappings are used for some key fields on
>   project_issue nodes:
>
> field_issue_priority
>
> 400,"Critical” 300,"Major” 200,"Normal” 100,"Minor" field_issue_status
>
> 1,active 2,fixed 3,closed (duplicate) 4,postponed 5,closed (won't fix)
>   6,closed (works as designed) 7,closed (fixed) 8,needs review 13,needs
>   work 14,reviewed & tested by the community 15,patch (to be ported)
>   16,postponed (maintainer needs more info) 18,closed (cannot reproduce)
>   field_issue_category
>
> 1,'Bug report' 2,'Task' 3,'Feature request' 4,'Support request'
>
> Available Taxonomy Vocabularies
>
> 1,Forums 2,Screenshots 3,Module categories 5,Drupal version 6,Core
>   compatibility 7,Release type 9,Issue tags 31,Page status 34,Front page
>   news 38,Audience 44,Maintenance status 46,Development status
>   48,Services 50,Sectors 52,Locations 54,Keywords 56,Level 58,License
>   60,Book availability 62,Book format