# Contrib statistics: Reported installs and downloads

Tags: community-official-site

I've noticed that the number of reported installs is usually (not always) somewhat larger than the number of downloads. I figured maybe this is because of multi-site installations in which one download runs on several sites. On the other had, there have to be cases where a module is downloaded and not implemented in production, which perhaps would account for cases where there are more downloads than installs.

But I just noticed that "[CKEditor Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link)" has over 50,000 reported installs and only 658 downloads. That doesn't make any sense. Does anyone know what's going on there?

These statistics are relevant to the decision of which modules and themes to use in a system. (Edit: They are relevant for me because I can't afford to be in a situation where my sites go down because a Drupal revision breaks a module and the module maintainers don't get it fixed pronto. This is much less likely to happen with an installed base of 50,000 than 500.)

Comment: statistics shouldn't be the deciding factor on modules, the applicability of that particular module to your needs should be - even similar modules differ in many respects, meaning one is likely to be more useful than another, regardless of how many people have used it

Comment: @Geoff, NewSites said "statistics are relevant" to a module/theme decision. This is true. It shouldn't be the _only factor_, but it should be _a factor_.

Comment: well, in my opinion that's poor thinking by a narrow minded author. If a module is specific, and only applies in very limited situations, it will have low statistics, naturally - but that doesn't mean it's a poor module or not useful, only that it is more specialised than something like Rules or Views

Comment: @Geoff - See the edit of my question to explain the relevance in my situation.

Comment: that's faulty logic, but this discussion doesn't belong here anyways...

Comment: @Geoff, statistics is clearly a factor (among others). In particular, the ratio installs/downloads  matters. A module with 10 000 downloads but only 10 installs (i/d ratio = 0.001) is likely to have been rejected by a lot of downloaders.  Obviously, this ratio number is only relevant when the download number is correct.  Currently, it is just a random number.

Comment: @FreeRadical well, you're wrong in your generalisation about how modules are chosen by the community at large - it's not 'clearly a factor', because I've never read the statistics to determine the applicability of a module to any of my projects - why would I care how many people have downloaded it, or have updates turned on in order to know if that module will work for me?  just because it didn't work for someone else's situation, doesn't mean it won't work for mine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: The problem is with a bug in the statistic module. Some information about sampling methods follows.

The number installs comes from the [Project module](https://www.drupal.org/project/project) used on drupal.org. On the [project usage page](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage), it links off to [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/329620) about usage statistics which states:

> As always with statistics of this sort, they don't tell the whole
>   story. For example, the results shown for "Drupal" are a poor estimate
>   of the number of Drupal sites on the internet. This is because only
>   sites running the Update Status module report data back to drupal.org.

Downloads are likely to have heavier bias, compared to installations, due to a number of factors limiting installation reporting (e.g. modules never installed, modules uninstalled, sites without Update Status running, etc.)

Comment: I'm wondering... Why you said core's statistics module is inaccurate. I don't use it any of my sites, but I'm pretty sure it uses a silent Ajax call after the page load to increment the counter. A cache won't have effect on this (front end cache, Memcache or Opcode caches).

Comment: I made a clarifying edit regarding 2 different sampling methods. Maybe core statistics is better in D7? In various D6 sites, I've had it report wildly different results (compared to other data statistics) when Boost caching was enabled.

Comment: While accepted, this answer is wrong. This has only been happening since mid-april 2015 - and its cause is a [bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2475039).

Comment: The statement: "the sampling is heavier in favor of install reporting vs. download reporting" is still wrong.  (It is actually the other way around. When it is working, the download counter counts every single download, while the install counter *only* counts sites that is running "Update Status".).

Comment: Missed that block of text on removal. Fixed the conclusion based on that info. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply due to a bug with the statistics module - see [Project Download count Decreased](https://www.drupal.org/node/2475039) - that has affected Drupal.org infrastructure since the middle of April 2015.

Prior to that bug surfacing, I did not observe a *single* project where the number of downloads were less than the number of installs.

Just now [**CKeditor Link**](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_link) is reported to have 487 downloads.  That is *171 less* than the 658 reported by the OP in the question (asked two days ago).

Until this bug is fixed, the *download* statistics should just be regarded as a random number.

As reported by Pierre.Vriens, [another bug](https://www.drupal.org/node/2178717) sometimes affect the *installed* statistic on the Drupal.org.  This affected many projects a couple of days ago, but seems to have been fixed for most of them today.

Answer (score 3):

Something seems really wrong these days with these statistics, and this for any of the modules I've been checking lately. As a (random) sample, consider the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module: similar issue. But there is more: look at the "[Usage Statistics](https://www.drupal.org/project/usage/charts)" page of the Charts module (or just any module): the typical numbers there get updated somewhere on Sundays. While these updates are happening (on Sundays), the date (line) is already added, but with a counter 0. However this week (since last Sunday), it has always been 0.

Anyway, about your last phrase: be careful in "only" using these stats. Instead you may want to consider many more (like 23?) criteria to help you make decissions. As I documented in (what I call) [maintenance scorecards](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985#scorecards). In this case they relate to charting modules (that's where my interest in Drupal mostly is). But you can apply them for any set of modules of course.

Note: I'd be interested in other criteria to be considered to evaluate modules. Feel free to "edit" that community page (or add comments to it) for any such criteria to be added to it.

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue, The Reported installs count is not updating for https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_googlenews_sitemap. Can anyone please help in finding a solution to this.